# Cover points with minimal number of spheres of fixed radius

Tags: algorithms, optimization, computational-geometry

I have a set of k n-dimensional points:

P<sup>1</sup>(x<sup>1</sup><sub>1</sub>, x<sup>1</sup><sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sup>1</sup><sub>n</sub>), P<sup>2</sup>(x<sup>2</sup><sub>1</sub>, x<sup>2</sup><sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sup>2</sup><sub>n</sub>), ..., P<sup>k</sup>(x<sup>k</sup><sub>1</sub>, x<sup>k</sup><sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sup>k</sup><sub>n</sub>).

A distance D(P<sup>a</sup>, P<sup>b</sup>) is defined between any two points, which satisfy usual properties:

1. D(P<sup>a</sup>, P<sup>b</sup>) >= 0
2. D(P<sup>a</sup>, P<sup>b</sup>) = 0 <=> P<sup>a</sup> = P<sup>b</sup>
3. D(P<sup>a</sup>, P<sup>b</sup>) = D(P<sup>b</sup>, P<sup>a</sup>)
4. D(P<sup>a</sup>, P<sup>c</sup>) ≤ D(P<sup>a</sup>, P<sup>b</sup>) + D(P<sup>b</sup>, P<sup>c</sup>)

What is the algorithm to find areas in which these points aggregate?
More specifically, given a radius R find the smallest set β of n-dimensional "balls" B(C) such that every point lies inside at least one of the balls:

ⱯP<sup>a</sup> ƎB(C) ∈ β => D(P<sup>a</sup>, C) ≤ R

There is definitely more than one solution (in most cases a ball could be moved a little so that it would still contain the points) and probably there is something else I am missing. But I need an algorithm that would provide at least one solution.

Example:

If
k = 5, n = 2, R = 2, D(P<sup>a</sup>, P<sup>b</sup>) = euclidean distance on a plane
P<sup>1</sup>(0,0), P<sup>2</sup>(1,1), P<sup>3</sup>(4.5, 4), P<sup>4</sup>(-4, 1), P<sup>5</sup>(4,4),

Then
B<sup>1</sup>(0.5, 0.5) (contains first two points), B<sup>2</sup>(-4,1) (contains only 4th point), B<sup>3</sup>(4,4) (contains 3rd and 5th points)

Comment: Yes, I need minimal number of balls. I would want to say that balls should not intersect, but it seems that there would be cases when the problem would be unsolvable. Probably then - minimal number of non-intersecting balls with radius _not more than_ R. Clustering seems to be what I need, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Construct a graph. Represent every point by a node and connect two nodes with an edge if the distance of the represented points is $\leq R$.

Then, a [minimial clique cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover_problem) of the graph tells you which points should belong to the same sphere, one per cluster; pick the center of each set as center for the sphere.

Unfortunately, Minimal Clique Cover is NP-hard so no efficient algorithm is known for it. There may be [algorithms suitable for your application](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/dealing-with-intractability-np-complete-problems/1481#1481) in the literature, though.

---

Does it get any better? I don't have a proof, but this feels like a [clustering problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) to me which tend to be NP-hard. You may want to try and apply the ideas of [hierarchical clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering).